# Non-Contiguous column grouping in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a reports that groups data into day and month in order to do year on year comparisons. It uses a trick I learned on SO with the SQL below to split between the current year and the one before.

```
select 
iif(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0,0,1) as [Row],
CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time])) as [daymonth],


  sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered],
  sum(iif([Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [Ring Offs]

  From inboundcallsview 

   where
   ([Start Time] between '2016-12-15' and '2016-12-22')
   Or
   ([Start Time] between '2015-12-15' and '2015-12-22')

   group by 
iif(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0,0,1),

CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time]))
```

When I put it all into SSRS using this setup,

[image: Setup]

I get this result, where 0 is this year and 1 is last year

[image: result1]

which is fine, but I would much prefer to get this result

[image: resultwanted]

So that people can more easily compare answered with answered and ring offs with ring offs. Is there a way either in the SQL or in the report set up to get the column grouping below the column headers as it were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the query posted by LONG didn't work for me (was running for 20 mins before I aborted it) but it did make me use my brain for once and point me in the right direction. What I've done is incorporate the Row distinction directly into each iif statement rather than having it sit above so the SQL is now

```
select 

CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time])) as [daymonth],


  sum(iif(([Type] in ('Normal operator call'))and(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0),1,0)) as [Calls Answered This Year],
    sum(iif(([Type] in ('Normal operator call'))and(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())<>0),1,0)) as [Calls Answered Last Year],
  sum(iif(([Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'))and(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0),1,0)) as [Ring Offs This Year],
  sum(iif(([Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'))and(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())<>0),1,0)) as [Ring Offs Last Year]


   From inboundcallsview 

   where
   ([Start Time] between '2016-12-15' and '2016-12-22')
   Or
   ([Start Time] between '2015-12-15' and '2015-12-22')

   group by 

CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time]))

order by CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time]))
```

And I got the output I wanted

[image: output]

So thanks LONG for making me engage my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using column group, try this query simply using table.

```
Select A.daymonth,B.[Calls Answered],A.[Calls Answered],B.[Ring Offs],A.[Ring Offs] 

 FROM 

 (
 select 
iif(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0,0,1) as [Row],
CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time])) as [daymonth],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [Ring Offs]

From inboundcallsview 

where
   ([Start Time] between '2016-12-15' and '2016-12-22')
 group by iif(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0,0,1),CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time]))
) as A

LEFT JOIN 

 (
 select
iif(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0,0,1) as [Row],
CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time])) as [daymonth],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [Ring Offs]

From inboundcallsview 

where
([Start Time] between '2015-12-15' and '2015-12-22')
 group by iif(DATEDIFF(yy,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [Start Time]), 0),GETDATE())=0,0,1),CONCAT(DATEPART(d,[start time]),'-',Datepart(m,[start time]))
) as B

ON B.daymonth = A.daymonth

Where A.Row ! = B.Row
```

Comment: This query gives me 8.5 million rows. Surely that can't be right?

Comment: let me double check

Comment: i have modified the query, try now